# What is $@ used for in Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, sh

Recently, I came across a function to put in `~/.bashrc`

```sh
gpip(){
   PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip "$@"
}
```

([Source](http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/))

I don't understand the use of `$@`. I guess that it sends to `pip` the argument passed to `gpip` from Terminal.

Is my understanding correct? What are those programming constructs called?

Comment: _"`$@` Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word."_ :: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html

Comment: or http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Comment: The code in your question wraps `pip` with `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV` set to the empty string for the duration of the `pip` run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$@"` is "interpolate all arguments, quoted individually", like `"$1" "$2" "$3"...`.

So...

```
gpip "foo bar" "baz"
```

will call

```
PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip "foo bar" "baz"
```

`man bash`, then search for "Special Parameters". (This is not Mac-specific, it is a <strike>`bash`</strike> POSIX feature.)

Comment: *[...] it's a `bash` feature.* More than that; `$@` is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02).